# Laravel 5.1 Event broadcasting seems to be irresponsive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been struggling with this for a day - I can't get to work laravel events broadcasting system. I use pusher. I followed the laracasts tutorial step by step several times,
In the pusher web interface I can see than connection is open but it is not able to listen to any of my broadcasting events. Why could this happen?

Step by step what I did:

Fire an event, make it implement `ShouldBroadcast` interface,

Implement `broadcastOn` method

Followed the JS code example from pusher docs to listen to this event.

```
var pusher = new Pusher('3890ebc2a16a21e534d8', {
        encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('pointsGiven.' + this.player.id);

    console.log(channel);
    channel.bind("MK\Events\PlayerWasGivenScores", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The event name is `App\\\Events\\PlayerWasGivenScores`.

No mistakes here - checked several times. So what could it be? The docs says that queues should be configured. is `sync` driver for queues considered as configured queue? I believe yes. Could this be a problem that I'm on homestead?

Any hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ahhh, how stupid this was. When referencing pusher credentials in the `.env` file I did `PUSHER_APPI_ID` instead of `PUSHER_APP_ID`. that's 2 days of efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect channel name; according to the pusher documentation:

> Channel names should only include lower and uppercase letters, numbers and the following punctuation `_ - = @ , . ;`

Your channel name therefor `MK\Events\PlayerWasGivenScores` is invalid. The same *might* be the case for the event names, I'd test this by using simpler channel and event names.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. isn't `pointsGiven.1` my channel name? And yes, I'd been testing it with something like `test` channel name - same result. As per event Event name - well, this comes from Laravel - full event name including namespaces. This is what Laravel docs say

Comment: I was referencing incorrectly my credentials in the `.env` file - had `PUSHER_APPI_ID` instead of `PUSHER_APP_ID` - my super bad

Answer (score 0):

Is this local or on a server? If on a server make sure ports are available for Redis and Node.

Comment: hi, It was me not paying much attention to details - see my comment to Luceos answer.